# publishing .net 5 + .net framework solution to azure with github actions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a .net 5 web api that consists of a solution with most of projects being .net 5, but two of them are .net framework (v 4.7.2).

The web api works fine when I run it, and referring to .net framework projects is not a problem.

Now I am trying to upload this solution to azure app service using Github actions. The build step works fine, but when publishing, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4288,5):
> error : MSB4803: The task "FormatUrl" is not supported on the .NET
> Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of
> MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details. [path
> to my .net framework .csproj]

I am trying to avoid updating the project to .net 5. Is there a way to configure my github actions to be able to publish .net framework projects as well?

Comment: the yml file is in a private rep so I cant share a link to it. Is there something specific you would like to check on the yml file?

Comment: did you ever solve this? It's now annoying me...

Comment: I ended up updating my .NET framework  application to .NET 5. It did work then, but I still don't know if it is possible to do what I was trying to do

Comment: Yea I've had to create a second project I've called Legacy for all my door her framework solutions. I didn't have door net core compatible components, so I couldn't upgrade.